# If $A$ is a trace class operator so is $|A|$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, trace

Let $A$ be a trace class operator on a separable Hilbert space $H$, I would like to show that $|A| = \sqrt{A^* A}$ is also a trace class operator. This seems to be a simple result, but I could not find a proof for it so I am trying to prove it myself.

Since $A$ is trace class, that means
$$tr|A| < \infty \implies \sum_{i=1}^\infty \langle \varphi_i, |A| \varphi_i\rangle < \infty$$
where $\{\varphi_i\}$ is any orthonormal basis for $H$. Thus for $|A|$ to be trace class we would like to show that
$$tr \big||A|\big|  < \infty \implies \sum_{i=1}^\infty \langle \varphi_i, \big||A|\big| \varphi_i\rangle < \infty$$
Let $|A|  =  V\big||A|\big| $ be the polar decomposition of $|A|$. Then
$$|A| = \sqrt{|A|^* U^* U |A|} = \sqrt{|A|^*|A|} = \sqrt{\sqrt{AA^*}\sqrt{A^*A}}.$$
But since $|A| \neq |A^*|$ in general I would need to show that $\sqrt{AA^*}\sqrt{A^*A}$ is positive, so I am not certain if this is correct.

Any hints?

Comment: How did $|A^*|$ creep into this?  All you need to show is that $\big||A|\big|=|A|$.  But $|A|$ is self-adjoint so $|A|^* |A| = |A|^2 = A^* A$.  So $\big||A|\big|, |A|$ are both a square root of $A^*A$, and since a square root is unique, they're the same.

Comment: What is your definition of a trace class operator ? According to [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class) $A$ is of trace class if ${\rm Tr}\,|A|<\infty.$ Besides the operator $|A|$ is nonnegative, so it  seems weird to look  for its polar decomposition.

Comment: Warning about the fact that $|A^*| = \sqrt{AA^*} \neq |A|^* = |A| = \sqrt{A^*A}$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I'm using the definition where an operator $A$ is in the trace class if and only if tr $|A| < \infty$.

Comment: @JohnDoe Thank you. I was missing the fact that $|A|^2 = A^* A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|A| \geq 0$ and $|A|^2 = |A|^*\,|A| = \big||A|\big|^2$, by uniqueness of the square root of a positive operator,
$$
\big||A|\big| = |A|.
$$
Hence, $A$ is trace class iff $|A|$ is trace class and
$$
\mathrm{Tr}\,\big||A|\big| = \mathrm{Tr}\,|A|.
$$

Comment: Thank you. We have that $|A|^2 = A^* A$, but how is this equal to $|A|^* |A|$?

Comment: A positive operator is self-adjoint, hence $|A|^*=|A|.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thank you.